# webrtc sdp attribute a=max-recv-ssrc

Tags: webrtc, sdp

I am receiving multiple camera tracks in single rtp session. In one of the document it is mentioned like we need to add sdp attribute `a=max-recv-ssrc:{*:4}` in the sdp offer. may i know how to add this attribute to sdp?

[https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-westerlund-mmusic-max-ssrc-00.html#:~:text=A%20given%20SSRC%20value%20is,(e.g.%20audio%20or%20video)](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-westerlund-mmusic-max-ssrc-00.html#:%7E:text=A%20given%20SSRC%20value%20is,(e.g.%20audio%20or%20video)).

Answer (score 0):

If the viewer is offering and the sender is answering you need to add transceivers. By doing the the following you are declaring to the camera you are willing to accept 4 video tracks.

```
let pc = new RTCPeerConnection()

// On for each camera track
pc.addTransceiver('video', {'direction': 'recvonly'})
pc.addTransceiver('video', {'direction': 'recvonly'})
pc.addTransceiver('video', {'direction': 'recvonly'})
pc.addTransceiver('video', {'direction': 'recvonly'})

// create the offer and send to camera....
```

Would you mind sharing the Session Descriptions that are being exchanged?

I am not sure what clients you are working with but [source.chromium.org](https://source.chromium.org/search?q=max-recv-ssrc&sq=&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc:third_party%2Fwebrtc%2F) doesn't have any hits for `max-recv-ssrc`

Comment: this is not supported in webrtc.